# windows 10, adding more functionality to keyboard keys

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

so basically I want to add more commands into a single key for e.g:

When ingame, I need to press Q for skill but after that I must press ctrl+6.

How can I combine both of them into the Q key? when I press Q it will activate the skill AND the ctrl+6.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is best accomplished with third party software that runs in the background in Windows:

http://lifehacker.com/5883003/the-best-key-remapper-for-windows

Some gaming keyboards come with this software. I use a Razer BlackWidow to remap some keys in "gaming mode" and disable the windows key while I'm in games: http://a.co/1ovAqem

The software that comes with this keyboard also allows macros of multiple keystrokes mapped to special macro keys.

Comment: I do all sorts of crazy stuff with cortex (the razer config tool). At the moment I have my macro keys running a small application which runs nircmd to switch my audio output...

Comment: that's a key Remapper, i need something else